# Trying to use a function to destroy tkinter frame that was created in another function. Unsuccessfully

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm very new to python programming and I've been unable to find out how to get this to function properly. I'm using frames to show a login screen prior to loading the main inventory frame. I intend to record changes to inventory per user, so this is necessary for the program to function properly.

The program calls the `Loginscreen()` and `LoginFrameGenerate()` functions to generate the top menu and the frame including labels and entry fields. (Using Tkinter)
The "Log In" button, once pressed, calls the `loginfun()` function.
The `loginfun()` function is supposed to use an if statement to check the username and password and if they are correct, remove the login screen frame. Once the login screen frame has been removed, the mainframe and menu functions are called.

Unfortunately, the login screen frame will not go away when using the `destroy()` command. I can't move forward until I can get this working. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I tried the function without re-initializing the frame inside the loginfun() function, but it generates a name error. I no longer get the name error, but the frame doesn't get destroyed. I've searched google and stack overflow for hours and the only thing I could find regarding Tkinter `destroy()` was in reference to classes. I'm beginning to think I've been coding this wrong and I should have made each frame a separate class.

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import sys

root = Tk()
root.iconbitmap('Favicon.ico')
testusername = "Admin"
testpassword = "Pass"
CurrentUser = StringVar()
Pass = StringVar()
root.state("zoomed")

def Exitbtnclick():
    sys.exit(0)

def logout():
    MainFrame=Frame(root)
    MainFrame.destroy()
    loginScreen
    loginFrameGenerate

def loginScreen():
    loginMenu = Menu(root)
    root.configure(menu=loginMenu)
    FileMenu=Menu(loginMenu)
    loginMenu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=FileMenu)
    FileMenu.add_cascade(label="Exit",command=Exitbtnclick)

def loginFrameGenerate():
#THIS CREATES THE LOGIN FRAME
    logframe = Frame(root)
    logframe.grid()

    UL = Label(logframe, text="Username:", font="Arial 10 bold")
    UL.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="E")
    UE = Entry(logframe, textvariable=CurrentUser)
    UE.grid(row=0,column=1)
    PL = Label(logframe, text="Password:", font="Arial 10 bold")
    PL.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="E")
    PE = Entry(logframe, textvariable=Pass)
    PE.grid(row=1,column=1)
    loginbtn = Button(logframe, text="Log In", command=loginfun)
    loginbtn.grid(row=3,columnspan=2)

def loginfun():
#THIS FUNCTION IS CALLED WHEN THE "LOG IN" BUTTON IS PRESSED
    global testusername
    global testpassword
    logframe = Frame(root)   

    if (CurrentUser.get() == testusername) and (Pass.get() == testpassword):
        logframe.destroy() #THIS IS THE PART THAT DOES NOT WORK
        initializeMainMenu
        initializeMainFrame
    else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Error!", "Invalid Username/Password")
        return

def initializeMainMenu():
    mainMenu = Menu(root)
    root.configure(menu=mainMenu)
    FileMenu = Menu(mainMenu)
    UserMenu = Menu(mainMenu)
    ItemsMenu = Menu(mainMenu)
    ReportMenu = Menu(mainMenu)
    mainMenu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=FileMenu)
    mainMenu.add_cascade(label="Users", menu=UserMenu)
    mainMenu.add_cascade(label="Items", menu=ItemsMenu)
    mainMenu.add_cascade(label="Reports", menu=ReportMenu)
    FileMenu.add_separator()
    FileMenu.add_command(label="Log Out/Switch User", command=logout)
    FileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=Exitbtnclick)
    UserMenu.add_command(label="Add/Remove Users",command=random)

def initializeMainFrame():
    ##Main Inventory Screen To Be Filled in once the user is logged in
       MainFrame = Frame(root)
    MainFrame.grid()

loginScreen()
loginFrameGenerate()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please mention the version of the python being used.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm using Python 3.7 64-Bit. I'm also using Visual Studio 2019 as my IDE.

Comment: You *cannot* destroy the login frame, as you have no reference to it.  `logframe` was a local variable within `loginFrameGenerate()`, and ceased to exist when that function returned.  (Creating another Frame called `logframe`, and destroying that in the hope that it will destroy the original, is basically voodoo.)  Making this variable global would be one way to still have access to it when you need it later.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thank you!